# How to grab the Token count in solana Web3

Tags: token, web3js, solana

Hey i want to fetch the token amount how do I do that? I have reached this point but want to hold just the value [image]

used this till here `console.log("Signature: ",hash.meta.postTokenBalances);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you what you need.  Let's use SOL as an example, which as 9 decimal places, such that `1 SOL = 1_000_000_000 lamports`

- `amount` is the total amount of lamports, so `90_000_000_000` in your example
- `uiAmountString` is the formatted amount of SOL, so `90.000000000` in your example

If you need to do calculations, you should hold on to `amount` to do the math, and `decimals` to display it.  If you only need to display, then `uiAmountString` will be easiest.

Comment: Yes that is not the issue. My query is when I try to display the uiAmountString I am getting an error :  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uiTokenAmount' of undefined.

I did the following code
console.log('Pre Token Balance: ',hash1.meta.postTokenBalances.uiTokenAmount.uiAmountString);

Comment: `postTokenBalances` is an array, so you'll need to do `hash1.meta.postTokenBalances[0].uiTokenAmount.uiAmountString`. More info at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#results-68